# change arrow position for mid-target edges

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a way to change the midpoint position of edge arrows. Currently it's set at 50%, but I'd like to be able to adjust this to 25% or 75% depending on the edge. Is there a variable/option I can call within:

```
{selector: 'edge',
    style: {
    'curve-style': 'bezier',
    'line-color': '#506368',
    'mid-target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
    'mid-target-arrow-color': 'black',
    'width': 1,
    }
},
```

Comment: It's somewhat frustrating. I have nodes with lots of edges, if I keep the arrow at 100% position then all arrows merge together. If I keep at 50% then the labels are hiding the arrow marks. 80%(or custom on) seems perfect I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's going to happen.  The only reason that the mid arrow is allowed is because the point has to be calculated anyway.  Arbitrary points become expensive for beziers.

Comment: can you point me to where in the script that calculation happens so I can test it for small cases?

Comment: It's not the same sort of calculation, as your case can't make the same assumptions or shortcuts.  You'd have to start from scratch.

Comment: You may want to look at [calculateArrowAngles()](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/v2.7.12/src/extensions/renderer/base/coord-ele-math.js#L1781) and [findEdgeControlPoints()](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/v2.7.12/src/extensions/renderer/base/coord-ele-math.js#L1152) to start.  It's not going to be a simple tweak though...